# Will Boost.Asio's async_read_some the whole message?

Tags: sockets, c++11, boost-asio

I am trying to receive a package via http in my C++ program. I am using Boost.Asio for that purpose.

In my *handleAccept* method I have this code to read the package:

```cpp
    // m_buffer is declared as: std::array<char, 8192> m_buffer;
    auto buf = boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer);
    newConnection->getSocket().async_read_some(
        buf,
        boost::bind(&TcpServer::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
    );
```

Is this enough to get any package? How do I make sure that it will get packages that are bigger than 8192 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async_read_some` reads a received message **up to** the size of the buffer that you give it. The number of bytes in a received message is returned in the `bytes_transferred` placeholder of the callback function, see [basic_stream_socket::async_read_some](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html)

If you know the maximum size of the messages that you expect to receive, you can simply use a buffer that is large enough for that message. Otherwise, you'll have to copy the contents of the `async_read_some` buffer elsewhere and build up the whole received message there.

Comment: OK that makes sense. So the way to go is to call handleRead recursively until `bytesTransferred` parameter of _handleRead_ is 0?

Comment: No, you will never receive `bytes_transferred` == 0. Your message protocol should tell you the size of the message body at the start of a message or disconnect the socket when complete. In the second case you'll have to check the `error` placeholder.